# Meaning of 'dead plumber'

Tags: meaning, context

'[The Penance](https://books.google.com/books?id=aU_sxUxGtE0C&pg=PA427&dq=%22soul+of+a+dead+plumber%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBWoVChMI4oyb2uGWyQIVU9JjCh3-7g3y#v=onepage&q=%22soul%20of%20a%20dead%20plumber%22&f=false)', a story of Saki, is about a dead cat. I am trying to understand a phrase in the following sentence from that story:

> That same evening when twilight was deepening into darkness Octavian took up his position as penitent under the lone oak-tree, having first carefully undressed the part. Clad in a zephyr shirt, which on this occasion thoroughly merited its name, he held in one hand a lighted candle and in the other a watch, into which the soul of a **dead plumber** seemed to have passed.

What is the meaning of the phrase 'dead plumber' in this context?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to reply to your question without reading the full  story.

Comment: Octavian had pulled his 2yr old from the muck of the pigpen, while wearing his normal attire - including a pocket watch, apparently. Doing his penance for the death of the tabby, he wore only a muslin thin cotton shirt (zephyr)  which the wind (zephyr) blew through, and held his watch which had not been cleaned yet, and so smelled like a sewer - the workplace of plumbers.

Answer (score 3):

"Dead plumber" isn't a typical English saying.

I'm guessing that he means the watch was unreliable in the way that a tradesman (plumber) was unreliable in the time that they would turn up.

In modern English - say a a watch inhabited by the "soul of a dead cable company customer support staff"

Comment: Close -- but I think the expression alludes to the plumber's  s l o w n e s s rather than his unreliability. Octavian's penance has a duration: *"For a long, long time?" "For half an hour," said Octavian. There was an anxious ring in his voice as he named the time-limit; was there not the precedent of a German king who did open-air penance for several days and nights at Christmas-time clad only in his shirt? Fortunately the children did not appear to have read German history, and half an hour seemed long and goodly in their eyes.* But your updated example is exquisite.